# Stop services from downloading secure urls

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download

I use amazon s3 to streaming media with amazon s3 they provide a secure url with a time limit and the this expires like below.

http://wp.video.s3.amazonaws.com/daisy_2x.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIDVCDVR32H7DCSNA&Expires=1382004775&Signature=gtYCQy2SAC44sEV6zDDTD0MZS%2Bs%3D

I found that, using Torch browser, it is possible to download the audio/video.

Is there anyway to stop this?

Thanks

Comment: "they" provide a secure URL... who are "they"?  Yes, it's possible to download the object, until the link expires... that's sort of the idea.  You notice that the link, by now, is expired... and will never work again.  You want to set the timeout short enough that nobody other than the authorized user will get their hands on the link before the time expires.  What are you asking?

Comment: They = Amazon S3. I am asking is it possible to stop users downloading via torch browser even if i set the expiration to 5 minutes as i am streaming secure audio files (i dont want people to download), it is still possible for people to download my secure audio in that time. I am asking is there another way to lock this down? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was initially confused by your question, because, I thought "well, *of course* people can download files if you give them a signed URL to an object in an S3 bucket."

When you said "download," I thought you meant "fetch an object using HTTP," but you were using it to mean "download *and save to a file*" -- which is the part you wanted to prevent.

You mentioned Torch, which seems to make it extra easy for people to capture links to media content, but any browser in possession of a signed URL for one of your objects could download it.

The short answer, then, is "probably not," although it depends on the setup you are using now.  Fundamentally, as my original reaction to your question illustrates, a signed URL to your files means your files are downloadable and can be saved to a file.

If you are using some kind of custom player that sends or can send a specific user-agent string, and that player speaks https, you could configure your player to set that value on the request, and then add a bucket policy with a condition that prohibits requests unless the user-agent string (that identifies the browser to the web server) matches a specific value.  The reason for the need to use https is that it is [trivially simple](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/) for a browser to change its user-agent string to match whatever it is you're expecting, and the only way to prevent that string from being discovered is if the request for the resource is never sent over the wire unencrypted, which would require https.

That's really a pretty weak mechanism, because if the magic value is discovered, you're back where you started, though it would limit the accessibility of your resources somewhat.

If you're not using a custom player, then I'm not sure why you wouldn't expect the files to be downloadable.

The only other mechanism that comes to mind would be to apply [DRM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management) to your files before uploading them to S3, which would require a player that understands the DRM format you're using.  This is how the music subscription site [rhapsody.com](http://www.rhapsody.com/) works.  You're in possession of the downloaded files, but they're encrypted and your player won't play them if it can't verify that you're still a Rhapsody subscriber.  I have no idea what the cost, complexity, or compatibility of such a solution would be.

Perhaps the bigger problem that makes this problem seem insignificant by comparison, is that if somebody wants a copy of your content, it [doesn't take much ingenuity at all](http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/CMM103) to pull your content through [a hole that is impossible to plug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_hole).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer Michael ;) i have just revisited this question after posting on some other forums amazon stopped replying and jplayer the audio player i am using said it something you just have to deal with, i like the drm solution but i can imagine users getting really frustrated with limited options to play their music on any device. I am trying to think if they is anyway i can do something with php to only allow the tracks to be downloaded once only???